# How to run a series of methods in the background sequentially

Tags: c#, sequence, background-process

In a program I am working on, query a device, for simplicity, let's say that it is a slow network request where the response can take 200ms.  I need the program to query 5 things over and over in the background, and update the UI with the responses it gets from these requests.  Occasionally, a user give a command that will result in another network request.  It will need to complete this task, then continue to do the 5 things over and over that it did before.

This is not ACTUALLY a network request, so one limitation of it is that these requests cannot overlap, only one can happen at a time, so I can't just spin off a bunch of threads.

My current idea is to set up some sort of queue that would be pseudo-coded like:

```
DoTaskA();
DoTaskB();
DoTaskC();
DoTaskD();
DoTaskE();
RequeueTasksABCDE();
```

And then add the user commanded requests to happen maybe after DoTaskE(), but before RequeueTasksABCDE().

From my research so far, I'm thinking of using [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to be the queue, but is this the good way?  Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: You might just want to "start a bunch of threads" with a single mutex. Check the lock keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a new worker thread and running your functions in the worker thread.

Comment: I am currently doing that, and my current way of dealing with the user comands is to pause the backroundworker, do the user commands, and restart it.  However that has proved to be unreliable in testing, and I think a queue of tasks is a better idea, but I'm not sure if my current idea layout for the queue is good practice.

Comment: One option might be to do the user command stuff in the worker thread too, marshalling back into the UI thread as necessary for UI calls. `foreach (tasks) { task(); userstuff(); }` -- something of that nature, with invoke stuff in `userstuff()`.